# Is the beginning mentioned in Mark 13:19, Mark 10:6 and Matthew 19:4 the same beginning in Genesis 1:1 and John 1:1? In these verses, who created?

Tags: word-study

Mark 13:19 ASV For those days shall be tribulation, such as there hath not been the like from the beginning of the creation which God created until now, and never shall be

Mark 10:6 ASV But from the beginning of the creation, Male and female made he them.

Matthew 19:4 ASV And he answered and said, Have ye not read, that he who made them from the beginning made them male and female

To whom did Jesus ascribe creation on these verses?

Comment: see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77467/hermeneutic-implications-of-in-the-beginning-of-johns-prologue/77473#77473  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/58257/is-the-beginning-mentioned-in-mark-1319-mark-106-and-matthew-194-the-same-be/58258#58258  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53680/do-genesis-11-and-john-11-point-to-the-same-identical-beginning/53687#53687

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77636/comparing-the-words-beginning-and-gods-word-in-2-peter-34-5-with-john-11/77654#77654  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/are-the-words-beginning-and-word-mentioned-in-1john-27-the-same-as-those-fo/66178#66178  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76258/does-hebrews-924-26-imply-mankind-was-sinning-since-the-beginning-of-the-world/76266#76266

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In A Beginning" vs. "In THE beginning"? Different implications?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23431/in-a-beginning-vs-in-the-beginning-different-implications)

Comment: This question has been asked in so many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.  And despite this very likely being a barbed question, I will take the bait.

There are a number of "beginnings" in Scripture.  Here is a sample:

**1. Creation week of Gen 1**

Gen 1:1 - In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.

- Matt 19:4 - "Haven't you read," he replied, "that at the beginning the Creator 'made them male and female
- Matt 24:21 - For then there will be great distress, unequaled from the beginning of the world until now--and never to be equaled again.
- Mark 10:6 - "But at the beginning of creation God 'made them male and female.'
- Mark 13:19 - because those will be days of distress unequaled from the beginning, when God created the world, until now--and never to be equaled again.
- Heb 1:10 - He also says, "In the beginning, Lord, you laid the foundations of the earth, and the heavens are the work of your hands.
- 2 Peter 3:4 - They will say, "Where is this 'coming' he promised? Ever since our ancestors died, everything goes on as it has since the beginning of creation."

**2. A beginning is very ancient (eternal) time**

- In the beginning was the word, and the word was with God, and the word was God.
- 1 John 2:13 - I am writing to you, fathers, because you know him who is from the beginning. I am writing to you, young men, because you have overcome the evil one.
- 1 John 2:14 - I write to you, dear children, because you know the Father. I write to you, fathers, because you know him who is from the beginning. ...

**3. The beginning of the Gospel and kingdom of God/Heaven**

- Mark 1:1 - The beginning of the good news about Jesus the Messiah, the Son of God,
- Luke 1:2 - just as those from the beginning having been eyewitnesses and servants of the word delivered them to us
- 1 John 1;1 - That which was from the beginning, which we have heard, which we have seen with our eyes, which we have looked at and our hands have touched--this we proclaim concerning the Word of life.
- 2 John 1:6 - And this is love: that we walk in obedience to his commands. As you have heard from the beginning, his command is that you walk in love.
- 1 John 2:24 - As for you, see that what you have heard from the beginning remains in you. If it does, you also will remain in the Son and in the Father. [This beginning is really the start of the Christian experience but placed here for completeness.]
- 1 John 3:11 - For this is the message you heard from the beginning: We should love one another.
- Acts 11;15 - "As I began to speak, the Holy Spirit came on them as he had come on us at the beginning.

**4. Unspecified beginning and miscellaneous**

- John 8:44 - You belong to your father, the devil, and you want to carry out your father's desires. He was a murderer from the beginning ...
- 1 John 3:8 - The one who does what is sinful is of the devil, because the devil has been sinning from the beginning. The reason the Son of God appeared was to destroy the devil's work.

**CONCLUSION**

Thus, "the beginning" namely creation weeks includes the creation of the world as alluded to in Matt 19:4, Mark 10:6, 13:19; and Gen 1:1.  However, John 1:1 refers to a an eternally ancient beginning, before time began.  See Ps 93:2, Isa 48:16, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To whom did Jesus ascribe creation according to these verses?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - these verses do not ascribe nor credit the creation. That is found in other places such as Isa 44:24, 45:18, John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2, etc.

Comment: To clarify, Mark 13:19's " God created" Mark 10:6's "Male and female made he them." and Matthew 19:4's "that he who made them from the beginning made them male and female" these verses do not ascribe nor credit the creation?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - of course they do (I should have been more precise) but it is only "God" - the other verses I quoted get more specific.